# Dropdown Menu Populated by Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I have a model Abc. It has a column in it's associated database called 'description'. I'm trying to figure out how to populate a dropdown menu with the contents of the description so that the user would be able to select through each of the choices and pick one.

Currently, my action in my controller has this:

```
@abc = Abc.all
```

As far as I understand, this should select all records in the database that is associated with the model Abc.

Then, in the view associated with this action, I have this:

```
    <select name="id">
    <%= @abc.each do |abc|%>
    <option value="<% abc.id %>"><%= abc.description%></option>
    <% end %>
```

The above is something I was trying to adapt off an example I found online, which isn't working. I think this is supposed to create a dropdown menu with option values set to ID of the database entries. Then the actual content of the dropdown menu is populated with the contents of the 'description' column of the database. This isn't working as of now. Currently giving me this error:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

on the:

```
<%= @abc.each do |abc|%>
```

line of code.

The example I was talking about is here:

```
<select name="user_id">
  <%= @users.each do |user| %>
    <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

The context of the example is here: http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms

I'm pretty new to rails, any help would be appreciated. I get the feeling that I'm misunderstanding something about rails itself since the 'each' method is rails' version of an iterator.

Comment: Do you have data in your `Abc` model's `table`? And comparing your code with example,you have missed `>` here in this line `<option value="<% abc.id %>"<%= abc.description%></option>`.

Comment: Yes, I populated my table with some test data. I fixed the bracket, but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you tell me your `action name` and the `view file name`?

Comment: Action name is index, and view file name is index.html.erb

Comment: Hmmm,then everything seems fine for me.

Comment: Huh. On a hunch I checked the model name again. I had ABC.all instead of Abc.all. It works a bit better now, although it does sort of just spill out of everything, as seen here: http://imgur.com/HL7yUFt   The dropbox only has the first entry from the database and then there is the matter of the rest of the database being displayed to the screen.